# Convert LocalDateTime of third party library to Timestamp

Tags: java

We are using `org.thirteen.bp` library to manage different format with timezone information. I have parsed the string value to LocalDateTime with its format but is there any way to convert `org.thirteen.bp.LocalDateTime` to `java.sql.Timestamp`?

Comment: It's not `org.thirteen` but `org.threeten` (three-ten) which refers to [JSR-310](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983209), the new date and time API that was added to Java 8. This library is a backport of the new API so that you can use it in Java versions older than Java 8. See https://www.threeten.org/

Answer (score 2):

> is there any way to convert org.thirteen.bp.LocalDateTime to java.sql.Timestamp?

## Yes: `DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp`

The [`DateTimeUtils`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) class provides [a conversion method](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html#toSqlTimestamp(org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime)).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-01-23T01:23:45" ) ;
java.sql.Timestamp ts = org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp( ldt ) ;
```

## …but…

You should know that storing a [`LocalDateTime`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDateTime.html) object by using a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) is a terrible hack.

The `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment, but `Timestamp` does.

The problem is that before the *java.time* classes and [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) came along, Java had no way to represent a date and time-of-day without a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So there was no class back then equivalent to the SQL-standard type of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. They faked it by using `Timestamp`. This is one of the many terrible design decisions made by members of the early Java team who clearly did not understand the issues involved in date-time handling.

For more explanation, see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56163534/642706) by Ole V.V. on a similar Question.

When you eventually move to Java 8 or later, and can transition from *ThreeTen-Backport* to using the built-in *java.time* classes, you can avoid entirely the use of `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2019-01-23T01:23:45" ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;  // Appropriately storing a date and time-of-day without zone/offset into a database column of type TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE.
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

Presumably, you are using are using *ThreeTen-Backport* because you are still using Java 6 or Java 7. That means you do not have JDBC 4.2 or later. So you must use the hack seen at the top of this Answer.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both modern & legacy) and in standard SQL.]

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the library you mentioned is fork of Java 8 Date and Time API.

You should be able to get the `java.sql.Timestamp` using below code

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(LocalDateTime.getLong(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS))
```

Comment: For this format "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSSSSZZ" i get 1970 date always. It is not giving me expected date

Comment: This Answer buys into the false premise that a `LocalDateTime` is the same kind of information as a `Timestamp`. They are not the same at all.

Comment: Thanks.. updated the answer. It was supposed to be INSTANT

Comment: Now I get `org.threeten.bp.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: InstantSeconds` (this is related to @BasilBourque’s comment).